# Why do std::future<T> and std::shared_future<T> not provide member swap()?

Tags: c++, c++11, future, swap

All kinds of classes in the C++ standard library have a member swap function, including some polymorphic classes like `std::basic_ios<CharT>`. The template class `std::shared_future<T>` clearly is a value type and `std::future<T>` is a move-only value type. Is there any particular reason, they don't provide a `swap()` member function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Member swap was a massive performance increase prior to `std::move` support in C++11.  It was the way you could move one vector to another spot, for example.  It was used in `vector` resizes as well, and it meant that inserting into a vector of vectors was not complete performance suicide.

After `std::move` arrived in C++11, with many sometimes-empty types the default implementation of `std::swap`:

```
template<class T>
void swap( T& lhs, T& rhs ) {
  auto tmp = std::move(rhs);
  rhs = std::move(lhs);
  lhs = std::move(tmp);
}
```

is going to be basically as fast as a custom-written one.

Existing types with `swap` members are unlikely to lose them (at least immediately).  Extending the API of a new type should, however, be justified.

If `std::future` is basically a wrapper around a `std::unique_ptr< future_impl >`, then the above is going to require 4 pointer reads, 3 pointer writes, and one branch.  And an optimizating compiler who inlined it<sup>1</sup> could reduce it down to 2 pointer reads and 2 pointer writes (using SSA<sup>2</sup> for example), which is what an optimized `.swap` member function could do.

---

<sup>1</sup> So it knows intermediate access to the `lhs` and `rhs` never occurs, thus the existence of `tmp` can be eliminated as-if once it proves `tmp` is empty and hence has a no-op dtor.

<sup>2</sup> [Static single assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form), where you break a program down such that every assignment to a primitive creates a brand new variable (with metadata).  You then prove properties about that variable, and eliminate redundant ones.

Comment: Why a member function and not a friend function for unqualified `swap`? -- I'm under the impression that gcc (4.8) is bad at optimizing `unique_ptr`s. While it does use SSE, it performs a lot of unnecessary operations. Maybe due to exception handling, but maybe also because libstdc++'s `unique_ptr` uses a `tuple` to implement the compressed pair of deleter and pointer, and tuple might be quite hard to optimize.

Comment: @dyp Sounds like a reason to make your optimizer better, rather than changing the language.  Or figure out a way to express the compressed-tuple idiom than a hard to optimized library-based `tuple`; if compressed `tuple` is that hard to optimize, maybe have a built-in `std::tuple`?  That probably goes to far; then a built-in primitive product type that makes implementing compressed `std::tuple` easy?

Comment: libc++ has a dedicated `compressed_pair` type, I think that already helps. At least with compile times. I was wondering about performance since Howard Hinnant seems not to like the copy/move+swap idiom because of performance reasons.

Comment: @dyp That is copy/move+swap to replace assignment, which is different.  The HH complaint is that it basically upgrades assignment to construction, and construction requires clearing of existing state on the destination.  You can often partially reuse the state on the destinaion when assigning to it rather than recycling it.  As an example, N times copy-assign to a vector that repeatedly copy-construct swaps does N allocations; the same that grows the destination buffer, and copy-assigns and copy-construct elements does as few as 0.

Comment: Ah, I thought that was a different concern of HH's (strong exception safety for assignment).